# ComboBox load with new data when data changes

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am new to WPF and C# programming. 
I have a combo box which shows where state to which user belongs to along with drop down to update the state if needed.This works perfect.
Issue is when I select a new user, the old data from the previous user is still displayed in the combobox. How to make sure that the combobox shows new data whenever user is changed.

Comment: First of all if you new in some programming language or technology read manuals before ask question on Stack Overflow. For C# and WPF it is MSDN and a lot of articles on the Internet. As for your issue I believe you don't fire `PropertyChanged` event for property used as `ComboBox` `ItemsSource` on user changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the following blog post for an example of how implement cascading `ComboBoxes` in WPF using the MVVM design pattern: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/17/cascading-comboboxes-in-wpf-using-mvvm/

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}" />

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding States}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedState}" />
```

---

```
public ObservableCollection<User> Users {
  get;
  private set;
}

public ObservableCollection<State> States {
  get;
  private set;
}

private User _selectedUser;
public User SelectedUser {
  get {
    return _selectedUser;
  }
  set {
    _selectedUser = value;
    States.Clear();
    //add the user's states to the States collection:
    States.Add(new State() { Name = "..." });
    //...
  }
}
```